# SELinux & ncsa_auth in Squid

Tags: squid, centos5, selinux

I'm trying to enable SELinux on a CentOS 5.5 server with Squid 3.1.12 that handles authentication via ncsa_auth.

When I turn off SElinux everything works fine, but when I enable it, Squid crashes on the authentication-plugin, ncsa_auth.

This is the error message:

```
May 29 19:12:21 us squid[1458]: Squid Parent: child process 1493 started
May 29 19:12:21 us kernel: printk: 27 messages suppressed.
May 29 19:12:21 us kernel: type=1400 audit(1306696341.922:74): avc:  denied  { execute } for  pid=1494 comm="squid" name="ncsa_auth" dev=xvda1 ino=610563 scontext=root:system_r:squid_t:s0 tcontext=user_u:object_r:usr_t:s0 tclass=file
May 29 19:12:22 us (squid): The basicauthenticator helpers are crashing too rapidly, need help! 
May 29 19:12:22 us squid[1458]: Squid Parent: child process 1493 exited with status 1
May 29 19:12:22 us squid[1458]: Exiting due to repeated, frequent failures
```

When SELinux is permissive, these are the warnings I'm getting:

```
May 29 19:25:27 us kernel: type=1400 audit(1306697127.741:81): avc:  denied  { execute } for  pid=1524 comm="squid" name="ncsa_auth" dev=xvda1 ino=610563 scontext=root:system_r:squid_t:s0 tcontext=user_u:object_r:usr_t:s0 tclass=file
May 29 19:25:27 us kernel: type=1400 audit(1306697127.741:82): avc:  denied  { execute_no_trans } for  pid=1524 comm="squid" path="/opt/squid-3.1.12/helpers/basic_auth/NCSA/ncsa_auth" dev=xvda1 ino=610563 scontext=root:system_r:squid_t:s0 tcontext=user_u:object_r:usr_t:s0 tclass=file
```

The ncsa-auth:

```
[bart@us NCSA]# ls -alZ ncsa_auth
-rwxrwxrwx  root root user_u:object_r:usr_t            ncsa_auth
```

I [*think*](http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/13/html/Managing_Confined_Services/chap-Managing_Confined_Services-Squid_Caching_Proxy.html) he expects the label to be `unconfined_u:system_r:squid_t:s0`, but I have no idea how to set it properly. After I tried setting it with:

```
chcon unconfined_u:system_r:squid_t:s0 ncsa_auth
```

I got the following error: `chcon: failed to change context of ncsa_auth to unconfined_u:system_r:squid_t:s0: Invalid argument`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just checked on a CentOS 5.6 system where I have squid + ncsa_auth working. The permissions on my `/usr/lib64/squid/ncsa_auth` are

```
ls -lZ  /usr/lib64/squid/ncsa_auth
-rwsr-x---  root squid system_u:object_r:lib_t   /usr/lib64/squid/ncsa_auth
```

If I set the permissions on `/usr/lib64/squid/ncsa_auth` to be the same as you have then I get exactly the same error message as you do.

```
chown root:squid /usr/lib64/squid/ncsa_auth
chmod 4750 /usr/lib64/squid/ncsa_auth
chcon system_u:object_r:lib_t  /usr/lib64/squid/ncsa_auth
```

fixes the problem on my system.

Comment: It was indeed in the wrong place, after I moved it and applied the permissions and context, it worked!

Answer (score 2):

That would be `chcon -t squid_t ncsa_auth` there, but on my RHEL5.5 machine, there is a rule allowing Squid execute rights on files labeled `bin_t`, which is probably what it should be, not `squid_t`:

```
allow squid_t bin_t : file { ioctl read getattr lock execute execute_no_trans open } ;
```

You can check this with `sesearch -s squid_t --allow`. The same rule exists for lib_t, see Iains answer.

The `squid_t` type is meant for the domain, not files. A file could be labeled `squid_exec_t`, but that is for the daemon binary, not helper files. To make a long story short, the file should probably be labeled `bin_t` and put in `/usr/local/bin`.

I suspect your ncsa_auth plugin is installed in a weird location. If you put it in `/usr/local/bin`, and run `restorecon -Fv` on it, Squid will try to execute it as a `bin_t` file, which is a lot more likely to succeed.

Comment: It was indeed in the wrong place, after I moved it and applied the permissions and context, it worked!